# Materialize (Framework) Character Count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I can't figure out why the character count is displaying as "1/101/10".

[image]

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avdbLG

It appears the "/101/" is a combination of the max-limit (10) and current count (1). As you type in the field, the "/101/" is incremented with the amount of characters typed.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <form class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input id="input_text" type="text" length="10">
        <label for="input_text">Input text</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" length="120"></textarea>
        <label for="textarea1">Textarea</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input#input_text, textarea#textarea1').characterCounter();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Nothing answered here worked for me.

This is how i got it working:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var textNeedCount = document.querySelectorAll('#input_text, #textarea1');
            M.CharacterCounter.init(textNeedCount);
});
```

Comment: there is no ID "beschreibung" in the question

Comment: Yes, this was just my solution. 

I edited it so it fits more to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Please remove the **initialization code**.

```
$('input#input_text, textarea#textarea1').characterCounter();
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because for some reason *two* spans for the character count are created. This is what the output looks like in HTML:

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
    <input id="input_text" type="text" length="10">
    <label for="input_text" class="active">Input text</label>
    <span class="character-counter" style="float: right; font-size: 12px; height: 1px;"></span>
    <span class="character-counter" style="float: right; font-size: 12px; height: 1px;"></span>
</div>
```

It seems [some one else has had this problem](https://gitter.im/Dogfalo/materialize/archives/2015/06/30), but no solution was provided there.

Answer (score 0):

at first please make sure data you wrote 
***data-length***
not just length
after how I know you must initialize only when you add dynamically, so you even don't need js part

for more read >> [materializecss.com -> forms](http://materializecss.com/forms.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an old version of materialize 0.97.3 and you can use the latest of jquery. This works fine for me

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"</script>`
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"</script>`

And put this below in a js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input#input_text, textarea#textarea1').characterCounter();
});
```